# Iterate random over cells of a 2d array that have given distance from array's center

Tags: python, arrays

Ok so I am trying to iterate over a 2d array, so as to assign a random integer to all the cells that are further from a radius to the center of the 2d array. Then I have to do this for another radius, so as to have a "target-shaped" 2d array.
This way of doing does not work as the randint does not iterate over all those cells that have distance from center > radius.
What for loop should work there ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import random

N = int(20)
ci,cj = 10,10 #center of matrix
rcenter = 5 #first radius
rsuburbs = 15 #second radius

zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))
# Create index arrays to zero_data
I,J=np.meshgrid(np.arange(zero_data.shape[0]),np.arange(zero_data.shape[1]))
dist=np.sqrt((I-ci)**2+(J-cj)**2) # calculate distance of all points to centre

city_inf = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))
city_inf[np.where(dist>rcenter)]=random.randint(50,60) #FAIL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated code based on the comment**

```
import numpy as np
import random

N = int(20)
ci,cj = 10,10 #center of matrix

radiuss = [5,10] # store all the radius's
rand_range = [(0,5), (8,9)] # store the randum number range for corresponding radius

zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))
I,J=np.meshgrid(np.arange(zero_data.shape[0]),np.arange(zero_data.shape[1]))
dist=np.sqrt((I-ci)**2+(J-cj)**2) # calculate distance of all points to centre

x = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))

for i, radius in enumerate(radiuss):
  y=np.ma.masked_where(dist>radius, x) 
  y=y.filled(fill_value=np.random.randint(rand_range[i][0],rand_range[i][1], size=(N, N)))
  x=y

print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 0. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 3. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 8. 8. 2. 2. 1. 1. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 0. 8. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 8. 1. 1. 0. 4. 2. 1. 3. 1. 3. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 4. 4. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 4. 4. 2. 2. 4. 0. 1. 0. 2. 8.]
 [8. 8. 4. 2. 0. 4. 1. 4. 1. 3. 0. 0. 2. 4. 1. 0. 1. 3. 2. 8.]
 [8. 1. 2. 3. 1. 4. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [8. 0. 1. 2. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 3. 1.]
 [8. 2. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 4. 3. 0.]
 [8. 1. 4. 3. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 3. 2. 1. 4.]
 [1. 0. 2. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 3. 3. 4.]
 [8. 2. 4. 4. 0. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2.]
 [8. 1. 1. 2. 4. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 1. 0. 3.]
 [8. 3. 4. 4. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 3. 0. 0.]
 [8. 4. 3. 0. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 1. 3. 2. 3. 2.]
 [8. 8. 1. 0. 0. 2. 4. 2. 1. 2. 0. 4. 2. 3. 0. 0. 3. 2. 0. 8.]
 [8. 8. 4. 1. 1. 4. 0. 4. 4. 1. 1. 4. 1. 1. 2. 3. 0. 2. 0. 8.]
 [8. 8. 8. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 2. 1. 2. 4. 1. 1. 2. 3. 4. 3. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 8. 8. 3. 2. 3. 1. 4. 0. 3. 3. 2. 3. 3. 4. 3. 8. 8. 8.]
 [8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8. 2. 3. 2. 3. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 8. 8. 8. 8. 8.]]
```

**Old**

I have modified your code to create "target-shaped" 2d array:

```
import numpy as np
import random

N = int(20)
ci,cj = 10,10 #center of matrix
radiuss = [5,10] # store all the radius's

zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))
# Create index arrays to zero_data
I,J=np.meshgrid(np.arange(zero_data.shape[0]),np.arange(zero_data.shape[1]))
dist=np.sqrt((I-ci)**2+(J-cj)**2) # calculate distance of all points to centre
city_inf = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))

for radius in radiuss:
  city_inf[np.where(dist>radius)]=random.randint(1,10)
print(city_inf)
```

Desired code output:

```
[[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 3. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5.]
 [5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5.]
 [5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]
```

The earlier second radius of 15 was too high to get the pattern so I changed it to 10.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. However, the objective is to have all cells in a same radius category to be a different random integer. So all those 5's should be random int within an interval, all those 3's random integers within another interval, and the sema for the center 0's.

Comment: Check the updated code. You can now add any number of radius's and their random number range. Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you!